# 90s countdown with javascript Closure

Tags: javascript, closures

```
exports.show_time = function(n, id) {
    for (var i = n; i > -1; i--) {
        (function(t) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                var $timer = $('#' + id);
                var str_time = t + "s";
                $timer.text(str_time);
                $timer.attr('unable', true);
                if (t == 0) {
                    $timer.text("get phone code");
                    $timer.attr('unable', false);
                }
                console.log(t);
            }, 1000);

        })(i);
    }

};
```

I write above code to implement 90s countdown on the page,but the page have no change at all,if I debug my code I can see the countdown on the page but the order is not right.Any body can help me.

Comment: How are you using the script/file? `exports` isn't commonly available for client-side JavaScript (barring tools such as `browserify`).

Comment: Last update: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31108624/1636522 :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a setInterval(), in your case you can creating `n` timers which will get executed after 1 second instead of executing in every 1 sec

```js
var exports = {};
exports.show_time = function(n, id) {
  var $timer = $('#' + id);
  $timer.attr('unable', true);
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var str_time = n + "s";
    $timer.text(str_time);
    if (n == 0) {
      $timer.text("get phone code");
      $timer.attr('unable', false);
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
    n--;
  }, 1000);
};

exports.show_time(10, 'time')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: and not get var $timer = $('#' + id); each time around I assume

Comment: thank you,it resolve my question.And I will change the second argument 'id' to a jquery $ object

Answer (score 1):

In your code the loop sets up all timers at the same time, hence they fire all together 1 second later. However, surprising that they do not fire in the correct order... Anyway, you might find the cause reading this great explanation about Javascript timers (from the creator of jQuery himself) :

> http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

That being said, here is a multipurpose countdown function :

```js
function countdown (sec, onTick) {
    onTick(sec);
    if (sec) setTimeout(function () {
        countdown(--sec, onTick);
    }, 1000);
}

onload = function () {
    countdown(3, function (sec) {
        document.write(sec ? sec + ' ' : 'BOOM!');
    });
};
```